# Object.prototype.myFunction breaks "prettify"

Tags: javascript, google-code-prettify

Google [prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) stops working when my `JS` file has a `Object.prototype.myFunction = function(...`.

I.e. when I have at least one new function defined inside the `Object.prototype`, It prevents `prettify` to show code on my web-page.

Even though, I don't try to show that `javasript` file inside prettify code viewer. I just use that js-file as a lib.

I wonder why.. and how to avoid this? There is No any error in the browser when it happens

Comment: sounds like prettify is poorly (un-defensively) coded. Use Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "myFunction", {value: fn}) to define the method instead of just tacking it onto the prototype. that should keep it from appearing in un-filtered for loops. someone else can beat you up for using object protos...

Comment: It helped. Btw. For Arrays.prototype.newFunction - it works. It does not like Object.- only.